# 2D Array for Heatmap

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am trying to create a 2D array that I will use to plot a heatmap.

The array needs to be n by n and have the highest value be at its epicenter with diminishing values further away like in the diagram below.

How could I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy for the array and matplotlib for creating a heatmap respectively.  Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# creating array using numpy
array=np.ones((9,9),dtype=int)
array[1:8,1:8]=2
array[2:7,2:7]=3
array[3:6,3:6]=4
array[4,4]=5
print(array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(array,cmap="PuBuGn") # cmap can be Greys, YlGnBu, PuBuGn, BuPu etc
# Create colorbar
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax,ticks=[1,2,3,4,5])
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("My bar [1-5]", rotation=-90, va="bottom")
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_title("My heatmap")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: is there a way for me to scale array to make it larger, say for a 100 x 100 array?

Comment: Yes, use a loop to define the values of an array. I didn't use it here as the matrix you have is simple..

Comment: I did this, but the values did not come out quite right
#LDO noise profile
LDO_ARRAY = np.zeros((100, 100))
for k in range(50):
    LDO_ARRAY[k:(100 - k),1:(100 - k)] = k

Comment: I added it as a separate answer as I cannot able to enter in comment..

Answer (score 0):

For automatically create an array, use a loop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lim=100
arr=np.ones((lim,lim),dtype=int)
for i in range(1,lim):
    arr[i:len(arr)-i,i:len(arr)-i]=i+1
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(arr,cmap="Purples") # cmap can be Greys, YlGnBu, PuBuGn, BuPu etc
# Create colorbar
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax,ticks=list(range(1,lim,5)))
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("My bar [1-50]", rotation=-90, va="bottom")
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

# Show all ticks and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_title("My heatmap")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```